# mod_auth_openidc error 400 Bad Request - too many cookies (?)

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, mod-auth-openidc

I have a container mapped by Nginx on **example.org/portia/test**, structured as follow:

- Container exposes only port 9001, where an Apache instance as proxy is listening.
- A Django server is running on 8000, all traffic for /api and /server_capabilities is sent to him.
- Another Django server is running on 9002, which handles websockets on /ws path.

[a scheme of my network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKiN8.jpg)

I'm trying to add OpenIdConnect authentication using the mod_auth_openidc plugin for Apache, I want to protect the entire virtual host.

So far I reach the correct login page on auth-example.org, I login with my credentials and the auth server redirects me with the correct URI. Ngnix answers me with a 400 error.

[request sent with a lot of cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMO7J.jpg)

The auth server is used by several application inside mydomain.org, so I guess something is wrong with my Apache configuration file.

For clarity's sake, I can't touch Nginx or the auth server confs.

apache_site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:9001>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /app/portiaui/dist

        ServerName www.example.org
        ServerAlias example.org

        #ProxyRequests On
        Alias /static /app/portiaui/dist

        OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://www.auth-example.org/auth/realms/master/.wel$
        OIDCRedirectURI https://example.org/portia/test/callback
        OIDCCryptoPassphrase <much secret>
        OIDCClientID portia
        OIDCClientSecret <much private>
        OIDCCookiePath example.org/portia/test/
        OIDCCookieDomain example.org


        <Location /static>
                Require all granted
        </Location>

        <Location /api> 
                Require all granted
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
                ProxyPreserveHost On
       </Location>

       <Location /server_capabilities> 
                Require all granted
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/server_capabilities
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/server_capabilities
                ProxyPreserveHost On
        </Location>

        <Location /ws> # mod_proxy_wstunnel is enabled 
               RequestHeader set Host "127.0.0.1:9002"
               ProxyPreserveHost On
               ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9002/ws
               ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9002/ws
        </Location>

        <Location />
                AuthType openid-connect
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie path setting in `OIDCCookiePath` only needs to contain the actual path, not the host. In fact I'd start without using any of `OIDCCookiePath` or `OIDCCookieDomain`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Hans Z. suggests me to change also `OIDCRedirectURI` in a relative path.

Setting `OIDCRedirectURI /callback`solved the issue: my Apache instance doesn't receives the entire URL `www.example.org/portia/test/callback` but only the last part of the path. This is due to the front side Nginx instance.

Comment: I believe there is a warning recorded in the log file when such a situation occurs.